# npm run build does not create build directory on elasticbeanstalk

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, npm, dockerfile, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I am still puzzled as to why the `npm run build` command on an elasticbeanstalk instance does not produce the build folder when when I build the dockerfile. Its definitely not a permissions issue as I can `mkdir` and touch new directory and file respectively. I even list it in the dockerfile and I can confirm that the build folder isn't there. 
Also the npm install works and I cal see all the installed libraries in there

However when I build the same dockerfile locally, I can see that it creates a `build` folder. So its definetely an environment issue. I read somewhere that sometimes npm install can time out on `t2.micro`. So I even upgraded to `t2.small`. Still the issue persists. 
Can someone help me figure out as to what is going on here ?

Below is my dockerfile

```
FROM node:alpine as builder
WORKDIR '/app'
COPY package.json ./
RUN npm install
COPY ./ ./
RUN ls
RUN pwd
CMD ["npm", "run" ,"build"] 
RUN mkdir varun
RUN touch var
RUN ls

FROM nginx
EXPOSE 80
RUN pwd
COPY --from=builder ./app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
```

Below are the elasticbeanstalk logs

```
i-0276e4b74ee15c98f Severe  29 minutes  18  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  --  0.03    0.28    0.2 0.1 99.7    0.0
Application update failed at 2018-12-29T06:18:23Z with exit status 1 and error: Hook /opt/elasticbeanstalk/hooks/appdeploy/pre/03build.sh failed.

cat: Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or directory
cat: Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or directory
cat: Dockerrun.aws.json: No such file or directory
alpine: Pulling from library/node
7fc670963d22: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:d2180576a96698b0c7f0b00474c48f67a494333d9ecb57c675700395aeeb2c35
Status: Downloaded newer image for node:alpine
Successfully pulled node:alpine
Sending build context to Docker daemon 625.7kB 
Step 1/15 : FROM node:alpine as builder
---> 9036ebdbc59d
Step 2/15 : WORKDIR '/app'
---> Running in e623a08307d5
Removing intermediate container e623a08307d5
---> b4e9fe3e4b82
Step 3/15 : COPY package.json ./
---> cb5e6a9b109b
Step 4/15 : RUN npm install
---> Running in 8a00eb1143a5
&#27;[91mnpm&#27;[0m&#27;[91m &#27;[0m&#27;[91mWARN&#27;[0m&#27;[91m

Removing intermediate container 8a00eb1143a5
---> c568ef0a4bc3
Step 5/15 : COPY ./ ./
---> cfb3e22fc373
Step 6/15 : RUN ls
---> Running in f6aad2a0f22e
Dockerfile
Dockerfile.dev
README.md
docker-compose.yml
node_modules
package-lock.json
package.json
public
src
Removing intermediate container f6aad2a0f22e
---> 016d1ded2f97
Step 7/15 : RUN pwd
---> Running in eaae644b1d96
/app
Removing intermediate container eaae644b1d96
---> 61285a5062ea
Step 8/15 : CMD ["npm", "run" ,"build"]
---> Running in 5cbca2213f4f
Removing intermediate container 5cbca2213f4f
---> 8566953eebaa
Step 9/15 : RUN mkdir varun
---> Running in a078760b6dcb
Removing intermediate container a078760b6dcb
---> 34c25b5aab32
Step 10/15 : RUN touch var
---> Running in d725dafc9409
Removing intermediate container d725dafc9409
---> 70195ffecb54
Step 11/15 : RUN ls
---> Running in b96bc198883c
Dockerfile
Dockerfile.dev
README.md
docker-compose.yml
node_modules
package-lock.json
package.json
public
src
var
varun
Removing intermediate container b96bc198883c
---> 1b205ffb5e3f
Step 12/15 : FROM nginx
latest: Pulling from library/nginx
bbdb1fbd4a86: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:304008857c8b73ed71fefde161dd336240e116ead1f756be5c199afe816bc448
Status: Downloaded newer image for nginx:latest
---> 7042885a156a
Step 13/15 : EXPOSE 80
---> Running in 412e17c44274
Removing intermediate container 412e17c44274
---> e1e1ea0c7dfb
Step 14/15 : RUN pwd
---> Running in 1bc298a11ef1
/
Removing intermediate container 1bc298a11ef1
---> 291575f13e2f
Step 15/15 : COPY --from=builder ./app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
COPY failed: stat /var/lib/docker/devicemapper/mnt/e2b112f1a046c00990aa6fc01e9fabc9e147420a214682a06637ef8cbcb9414a/rootfs/app/build: no such file or directory
Failed to build Docker image aws_beanstalk/staging-app, retrying...
Sending build context to Docker daemon 625.7kB
```

Answer (score 3):

Oh my god..Finally after 1 full day of tinkering everything on aws, figured it out. I was using `CMD` instead of `RUN` to execute the command `npm run build`. CMD doesn't actually run it when you are building a dockerfile. So the folder isn't actually there for my second image to use.

Comment: Thanks a lot, your answer was really helpful. I was having the same issue